Jackrabbit standalone error ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
I'm trying to setup standalone jackrabbit server for development purposes but I'm unable to due to missing dependencies in .jar file. I've tried version 2.22.0 and 2.23.0 on ubuntu 22. I am pretty new to any Java development, but I tried to replace this dependency with org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver and org.apache.derby.client.ClientAutoloadedDriver by parameter driver in the config but result was the same.
I've also tried to change manager to org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.MySqlPersistenceManager but this resulted in error that I'm missing URL in params (which was there and I tried different variants of the param name).
My error:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver

Whole stack:
2024-07-23 21:50:30.280 ERROR [main] RepositoryImpl.java:370           failed to start Repository: Cannot instantiate persistence manager org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.DerbyPersistenceManager
javax.jcr.RepositoryException: Cannot instantiate persistence manager org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.DerbyPersistenceManager
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.createPersistenceManager(RepositoryImpl.java:1381)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.createVersionManager(RepositoryImpl.java:514)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.<init>(RepositoryImpl.java:315)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.create(RepositoryImpl.java:617)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryContext.create(RepositoryContext.java:156)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.servlet.jackrabbit.JackrabbitRepositoryServlet.init(JackrabbitRepositoryServlet.java:109)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:632)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.lambda$initialize$0(ServletHandler.java:750)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:357)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1449)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1414)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:916)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.standalone.Main.run(Main.java:247)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.standalone.Main.main(Main.java:96)
Caused by: javax.jcr.RepositoryException: Could not load JDBC driver class org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.util.db.ConnectionFactory.getDriverClass(ConnectionFactory.java:270)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.util.db.ConnectionFactory.createDataSource(ConnectionFactory.java:238)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.util.db.ConnectionFactory.getDataSource(ConnectionFactory.java:174)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.BundleDbPersistenceManager.getDataSource(BundleDbPersistenceManager.java:569)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.BundleDbPersistenceManager.init(BundleDbPersistenceManager.java:537)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.DerbyPersistenceManager.init(DerbyPersistenceManager.java:249)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.createPersistenceManager(RepositoryImpl.java:1377)
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.util.db.ConnectionFactory.getDriverClass(ConnectionFactory.java:265)
    ... 41 common frames omitted

my default config:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
   Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
   contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
   this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
   The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
   (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
   the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
   See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
   limitations under the License.
-->

<!DOCTYPE Repository
          PUBLIC "-//The Apache Software Foundation//DTD Jackrabbit 2.0//EN"
          "http://jackrabbit.apache.org/dtd/repository-2.0.dtd">

<!-- Example Repository Configuration File
     Used by
     - org.apache.jackrabbit.core.config.RepositoryConfigTest.java
     -
-->
<Repository>
    <!--
        virtual file system where the repository stores global state
        (e.g. registered namespaces, custom node types, etc.)
    -->
    <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem">
        <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/repository"/>
    </FileSystem>

    <!--
        data store configuration
    -->
    <DataStore class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.data.FileDataStore"/>

    <!--
        security configuration
    -->
    <Security appName="Jackrabbit">
        <!--
            security manager:
            class: FQN of class implementing the JackrabbitSecurityManager interface
        -->
        <SecurityManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.DefaultSecurityManager" workspaceName="security">
            <!--
            workspace access:
            class: FQN of class implementing the WorkspaceAccessManager interface
            -->
            <!-- <WorkspaceAccessManager class="..."/> -->
            <!-- <param name="config" value="${rep.home}/security.xml"/> -->
        </SecurityManager>

        <!--
            access manager:
            class: FQN of class implementing the AccessManager interface
        -->
        <AccessManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.DefaultAccessManager">
            <!-- <param name="config" value="${rep.home}/access.xml"/> -->
        </AccessManager>

        <LoginModule class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.authentication.DefaultLoginModule">
           <!-- 
              anonymous user name ('anonymous' is the default value)
            -->
           <param name="anonymousId" value="anonymous"/>
           <!--
              administrator user id (default value if param is missing is 'admin')
            -->
           <param name="adminId" value="admin"/>
        </LoginModule>
    </Security>

    <!--
        location of workspaces root directory and name of default workspace
    -->
    <Workspaces rootPath="${rep.home}/workspaces" defaultWorkspace="default"/>
    <!--
        workspace configuration template:
        used to create the initial workspace if there's no workspace yet
    -->
    <Workspace name="${wsp.name}">
        <!--
            virtual file system of the workspace:
            class: FQN of class implementing the FileSystem interface
        -->
        <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem">
            <param name="path" value="${wsp.home}"/>
        </FileSystem>
        <!--
            persistence manager of the workspace:
            class: FQN of class implementing the PersistenceManager interface
        -->
        <PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.DerbyPersistenceManager">
          <param name="url" value="jdbc:derby:${wsp.home}/db;create=true"/>
          <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="${wsp.name}_"/>
        </PersistenceManager>
        <!--
            Search index and the file system it uses.
            class: FQN of class implementing the QueryHandler interface
        -->
        <SearchIndex class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.SearchIndex">
            <param name="path" value="${wsp.home}/index"/>
            <param name="supportHighlighting" value="true"/>
        </SearchIndex>
    </Workspace>

    <!--
        Configures the versioning
    -->
    <Versioning rootPath="${rep.home}/version">
        <!--
            Configures the filesystem to use for versioning for the respective
            persistence manager
        -->
        <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem">
            <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/version" />
        </FileSystem>

        <!--
            Configures the persistence manager to be used for persisting version state.
            Please note that the current versioning implementation is based on
            a 'normal' persistence manager, but this could change in future
            implementations.
        -->
        <PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.DerbyPersistenceManager">
          <param name="url" value="jdbc:derby:${rep.home}/version/db;create=true"/>
          <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="version_"/>
        </PersistenceManager>
    </Versioning>

    <!--
        Search index for content that is shared repository wide
        (/jcr:system tree, contains mainly versions)
    -->
    <SearchIndex class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.SearchIndex">
        <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/repository/index"/>
        <param name="supportHighlighting" value="true"/>
    </SearchIndex>

    <!--
        Run with a cluster journal
    -->
    <Cluster id="node1">
        <Journal class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.journal.MemoryJournal"/>
    </Cluster>
</Repository>

My versions:
java -version
openjdk version "11.0.23" 2024-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.23+9-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu122.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.23+9-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu122.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)

javac -version
javac 11.0.23


It seems barely credible, since the standalone jar is chock full of libraries, but I had to download derby and put it all its jars in the classpath tp get it running

And this was my command: java -cp derbyclient.jar:derby.jar:derbynet.jar:derbyoptionaltools.jar:derbyrun.jar:derbyshared.jar:derbytools.jar:jackrabbit-standalone-2.22.0.jar org.apache.jackrabbit.standalone.Main

(1) download "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/derby/derby/10.14.2.0/derby-10.14.2.0.jar" (2) run command java -cp "jackrabbit-standalone-2.22.0.jar:derby-10.14.2.0.jar" org.apache.jackrabbit.standalone.Main (3) Only 2 jar files: (a) jackrabbit-standalone-2.22.0.jar (b) derby-10.14.2.0.jar  (Apache Derby Database Engine and Embedded JDBC Driver » 10.14.2.0)

FIX WARN MESSAGE: /jackrabbit/log/jackrabbit.log -> 2024-07-24 12:41:11.740 WARN  [main] ... java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.xerces.util.SecurityManager cannot be cast to class org.apache.xerces.util.SecurityManager (org.apache.xerces.util.SecurityManager is in unnamed module of loader 'app';...  open jackrabbit-standalone-2.22.0.jar , find /WEB-INF/lib/xercesImpl-2.12.2.jar , delete /xercesImpl-2.12.2.jar then save and close jackrabbit-standalone-2.22.0.jar, rerun start command , then no more WARN Message.

@life888888 both of your fixes worked, could you add them as an answer, so I can mark question as answered?

Download Derby Jar
download "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/derby/derby/10.14.2.0/derby-10.14.2.0.jar"
Only 2 jar files:

jackrabbit-standalone-2.22.0.jar
derby-10.14.2.0.jar (Apache Derby Database Engine and Embedded JDBC Driver » 10.14.2.0)

run command
java -cp "jackrabbit-standalone-2.22.0.jar:derby-10.14.2.0.jar" org.apache.jackrabbit.standalone.Main
FIX WARN MESSAGE
/jackrabbit/log/jackrabbit.log
2024-07-24 15:08:35.072 WARN  [main] XMLReaderUtils.java:850           SAX Security Manager could not be setup [log suppressed for 5 minutes]
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.xerces.util.SecurityManager cannot be cast to class org.apache.xerces.util.SecurityManager (org.apache.xerces.util.SecurityManager is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; org.apache.xerces.util.SecurityManager is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader @5386659f)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setProperty(Unknown Source)


use any zip tools open jackrabbit-standalone-2.22.0.jar

find /WEB-INF/lib/xercesImpl-2.12.2.jar

delete xercesImpl-2.12.2.jar

then save and close jackrabbit-standalone-2.22.0.jar

run start command again,


java -cp "jackrabbit-standalone-2.22.0.jar:derby-10.14.2.0.jar" org.apache.jackrabbit.standalone.Main

then no more WARN Message.

If you believe you found a bug in the standalone jar, by all means open a ticket in the Jackrabbit JIRA.
